# Erro no POST com API Rest - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, rest, django-rest-framework

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro (POST) esse endpoint https://geradornf-prod.herokuapp.com/ (é uma API Simples que eu fiz com Django Rest)

Estou usando Windows Forms C#

Segue a chamada:

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UtilDAO.UrlApi());
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/emitente", emitente);
                return response;
            }
```

E esta me retornando 500

```
{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
   Connection: keep-alive
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
   Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2016 23:05:36 GMT
   Server: gunicorn/19.6.0
   Via: 1.1 vegur
   Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

Alguem saberia o que pode ser?

o GET Funciona!

Caso queriam ver a API vejam em : https://github.com/leonardocintra/GeradorNf-e-API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro do 500.

o endereco estava assim:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/emitente", emitente);
```

Achei que passando o URL no `client.BaseAddress` com o "/emitente" era suficiente

A forma que funciona seria assim:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress.AbsolutePath + "emitente/" , emitente);
```